# How can I design a (PID) Controller if I don't have a reference signal?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, pi-controller

I have been trying to control lateral and longitudinal movement of a robot for an autonomous lane keeper project. I have no problem with the lateral movement, however I couldn2t figure out exactly how to control the longitudinal,
What I have in my mind is to lower the base speed of the vehicle as the lane angle increases (sharp turns), which can be expressed as

$$ Base_{Speed}=Max_{Speed}-K_1*Lane_{angle} $$

where $K_1$ is a constant that determines how much the vehicle should beslow down.

My question is how can I proceed with this longtidual speed control considering this expression seemed very basic . As of now I have no real speed information coming from sensors (encoders), but you may assume I have.

Thank you!

Comment: As I understand correctly, you are missing the signal $\frac{d}{dt}Lane_{angle}$. Why don't you do a differentiation on the $Lane_{angle}$ signal?

Comment: Hello Martin, thank you for your answer. I can differentiate the angle signal, however, I couldn't figure out exactly how it fits in the control system. Assuming I supple this angle information as a feedback, the structure lacks a reference signal to compare. Or doesn't it?

Comment: Edit : @MartinRosenau I forgot to mention you.

Comment: Shouldn't you just use 0 as the reference signal for $d_t \text{Lane}_{\text{angle}}$? If there's no change in the rate at which a turn is occurring, shouldn't the speed stay constant in regards to rate of turn?

Comment: Hi @MichaelSparapany it is a rather interesting idea, I also tought giving a zero ref, but how about the controlled variable. I do not have a control over the lane angle. Do you suggest a block diagram similar to what I posted below? Thank you anyway!

Comment: @MichaelSparapany  [An example block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVlB0.png)

Comment: Do you have waypoints? Or how do you control the lateral movement?

Comment: I'm not too well versed in block diagram notation, but something doesn't quite look right. Lane_angle is the output? Are you sure that's what you really want here?

Comment: @MachineLearner I use the difference btwn ICF and LCF (from the pic below) as a control variable with zero reference signal. To be more clear, a PWM signal generated from this distance to turn the robot with diifferencial pair. While doing so, I want to change the base PWM of the motor considering the lane_angle (beta from the pic).  
[img][https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dp4v.png]

Comment: @MichaelSparapany, I dont want it as a output signal, it is coming from lane independent from me but I couldnt fit the structure in a block diagram :((

Answer (score 0):

Your reference speed must be Base_speed and the speed that you read from your encoders will be your output and lets call it Current_speed. You will get an error as,

Base_speed=Max_speed−K1∗Lane_angle

Error = Base_speed - Current_speed

And you need to design a controller which will give a control input to your motors.

Something like this: Control_input = Kp*error+...

Comment: But that is not entirely true, ı do not want to push vehicle speed towards the base speed. That would be meaningless, what I want is to change base speed with changing line angle that you do not even use

Comment: I wanted to mention the same Base_speed as you used in your formula, so I use the lane angle.